# How to update screen immediately after changing an image's source with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wanting to show a new image in an existing `<img>` tag.  To accomplish this, I'm updating the `src` attribute via Javascript.  However, after changing the `src`, the screen doesn't change to show the new image loading.  Instead, it waits until the new image is fully downloaded, then swaps it in.

In reality, I'm setting the `background-image` of the `<img>` tag to the URL of the *thumbnail* of the image being loaded.  The goal being to have a poor quality image in place that gets gradually replaced with the good quality version.  However, since the new image doesn't appear while loading, all I get is the *old* photo sitting there until the new one suddenly appears.

A simplified example is below.  To really see the effect, open your DevTools > Network and set throttling to something slow.  Click on the image, then wait until it suddenly changes.  This is happening in Firefox and Chrome, so I'm guessing it's by design.

Any ideas how to bypass this behaviour?

```js
const images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/4/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/5/200/300"
];
let index = 0;
const length = images.length;
const img = document.querySelector("img");

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  index++;
  img.src = images[index % length];
});
```

```html
<img src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" />
```

Comment: @Robo Kind of.  I'd like the existing image to go away, revealing the thumbnail image I have set as the `background-image`.  Then, as the new image is downloaded, it gets displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the current image disappear while the new image is loading, you need to remove its `src` attribute.
However for your `<img>` to have a size, you need to set it explicitly (here I've done it through CSS).

```js
const images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/4/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/5/200/300"
];
let index = 0;
const length = images.length;
const img = document.querySelector("img");

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  index++;
  img.removeAttribute("src");
  img.src = images[index % length];
});
```

```css
img { background: red; width: 200px; height: 300px }
```

```html
<img src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" />
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to wrap my head around how to do this with my current Vue setup, but the advice seems solid.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively do this:

- Add a Loader/Loading text for the image.
- Remove the source attribute when you click on the image
- Show the loader while the source is being replaced.

```js
const images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/4/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/5/200/300"
];
let index = 0;
const length = images.length;
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const div = document.querySelector("div");

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  img.removeAttribute("src");
  index++;
  img.src = images[index % length];
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" />
<div class="div">Loading...</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qk62ua8/2/)